# Smart sorting by release date and version

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting

For one of our internal tools we would like to add some smart sorting for the executables.

Let's take this as an example:

```
        var unsortedItems = new[]
        {
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-01"), Version = new Version(3, 2, 1, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-01-01"), Version = new Version(1, 3, 1, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-02-01"), Version = new Version(3, 2, 2, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-02-01"), Version = new Version(1, 3, 0, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-01-01"), Version = new Version(3, 4, 1, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-03-01"), Version = new Version(3, 4, 2, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-02-01"), Version = new Version(1, 6, 2, 0)},
        };

        var sortedItems = new[]
        {
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-02-01"), Version = new Version(1, 6, 2, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-01-01"), Version = new Version(1, 3, 1, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-02-01"), Version = new Version(1, 3, 0, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-03-01"), Version = new Version(3, 4, 2, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-01-01"), Version = new Version(3, 4, 1, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-02-01"), Version = new Version(3, 2, 2, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-01"), Version = new Version(3, 2, 1, 0)},
        };
```

However, look at this example:

```
var unsortedItems = new[]
        {
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-01"), Version = new Version(3, 2, 1, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-03-01"), Version = new Version(6, 3, 1, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-02-01"), Version = new Version(3, 2, 2, 0)},
            new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-01"), Version = new Version(3, 4, 1, 0)},
        };

// Note that the 2009-03-01 seems off compared to the rest (this is just a single case).

// One variant 
var sortedItems = new[]
            {
                new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-01"), Version = new Version(3, 4, 1, 0)},
                new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-03-01"), Version = new Version(6, 3, 1, 0)},
                new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-02-01"), Version = new Version(3, 2, 2, 0)},
                new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-01"), Version = new Version(3, 2, 1, 0)},
            };


// Or this is acceptable too since it's pretty much a rotten apple
var sortedItems = new[]
            {
                new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-01"), Version = new Version(3, 4, 1, 0)},
                new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-02-01"), Version = new Version(3, 2, 2, 0)},
                new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-01"), Version = new Version(3, 2, 1, 0)},
                new {ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2009-03-01"), Version = new Version(6, 3, 1, 0)},                
            };
```

The problem is this, we used to sort by version but this isn't always possible when the version number changes drastically (to a lower one). We can't always sort by release date either because we found this to be unreliable (some executables have a release date that doesn't match with the version). So we'd like to somehow combine these values into a sorting that takes both into account. In the example above, it's rather clear that the versioning switched around 2011 to a lower numbering system. I was thinking about doing a minimum interval (let's say 1 year) to distinguish different groups by their version and then to sort by their version, but I'm not entirely sure if this will result in a sorting that makes total sense to the user (for a user, these patterns in versioning are not that hard to see). Is there anything that I should look into for these kind of sortings?

Comment: Is this *real data?* Was there really a release on `3/1/2011` in the `3.*` versioning scheme and a release *prior to that* on `2/1/2011` in the `1.*` versioning scheme?

Comment: Yes, this is unfortunately based on real data (except for the day which I just copied for simplicity). This is also why I need a better sorting than just the regular sorting (and also to exclude one-timers of a high version number).

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - Please use metric date format to avoid confusion - yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Could you provide an array of unsorted items and then an example of array with items the way you want it to be sorted?

Comment: I added two full examples that give an idea about the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a `(date, major version, major version placeholder)` tuple to your algorithm that says "separate all versions with given `major version` into two groups, one before and one on-or-after the given `date` and treat them as if they are independent versions (which they are), and while sorting versions place this 'after' version group immediately after the given `major version placeholder`, as if it's the next major version".

So for your example with four elements if you want the first outcome you would provide this tuple to the algorithm:

```
(2014-01-01, 3, 6)
```

If you really wanted the second outcome then provide this tuple:

```
(2009-01-01, 3, 6)
```

Instead of major version you could also work with complete four-part versions. The logic would be the same.

Comment: This looks like an interesting approach but leans on the fact that you have to know the version up front (I do not know that). With the real data it is also possible that there are multiple groups (let's say one with major version 3, one with 6 and one with 7).

Comment: Then you would introduce three such tuples. There's no other way to treat exceptions than to mark them as such. Imagine that several humans should do this work, given only dates and versions. I bet each of them would give you its own vision of what is right.

Comment: Well, it's pretty obvious to the normal eye what to do (nobody did this wrong thus far). Plus, it it not always be possible to sort by major. Take 1.0.0.1, 1.0.0.2, 1.2.0.1, 1.0.0.3 for example. That means I would have to 'skip' 1.2.0.1 like before.